# CodeError for Functions

Tags: python, pycharm, pseudocode

Here is the code for my question. I was trying to translate a pseudocode into python. The function, ExCamel, forms a return string, OutString, from a given string,InString,by:
1:Separating the original words(a word is assumed to start with a capital letter)
2:Converting all characters to lower case.

```
InString=str(input("Enter a statement: "))
def ExCamel(InString):
    NextChar=chr()
    OutString=str()
    n=int()
    OutString=""
    return OutString
for n in range(1,len(ExCamel(Instring))):
    NextChar=InString[n:n+1]
    if NextChar==upper(NextChar):
        if n>1:
            OutString=OutString+""
        NextChar=lower(NextChar)
    OutString=OutString+NextChar
```

But it gives an output of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/George/TrynaCreate.py", line 7, in <module>
    for n in range(1,len(ExCamel(Instring))):
NameError: name 'Instring' is not defined
```

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive. Replace `Instring` with `InString` and you won't get this error.

Comment: But you will get a next error, on `chr()`. (I cannot see the logic in your program so I can't help you with that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just seems like a silly mistake which happens with most of us:
you have defined

`InString`

but you are using `In's'tring`

Hope that helps :)